# Efficiently match a database of phone number prefixes to a phone number?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've got a database table full of phone number prefixes and how much per minute each one costs. The phone prefixes can vary in length a lot, from one digit to lots (5-6 or more).

Some of the prefixes will overlap, for example there is usually a default country per minute rate, so the more specific mobile rate must override the less specific rate.

Currently the way I am thinking of doing it is doing a while loop checking for the number in the prefix table, and each loop removing the last digit off the end. This is very accurate however it does do a lot of queries since a number could be 12 digits long and the relevant prefix is ~4 digits.

Is there a better way?

Update: Here is a screenshot of the table, the first column is the description, 2nd is the call rate and the third is a phone prefix.
[image: Phone cost table]

The challenge is to match a real phone number like say 61412345678 to the most applicable prefix without needing as many queries as my current method.

Comment: can you please clarify a little bit more, preferably with screenshots or table structure with data?

Comment: Yep sure got a screenshot of the table.

Comment: why dont you take a substring and match it against the column with the prefixes...so say you do have 12 digits just take 4 of those and match...grab that columns corresponding ID or whatever the data you need that is assocaited with that row to continue processing from there...not sure why you would loop through the number from the end...

Comment: Good problem, i would say. you can think like this:
1. in a while loop, first find strlen(prefix). for example, 
phone number is 61412345678
and first prefix is 61, so we will get strlen(61)=2 and compare this prefix to phone number, if matches, we will store that strlen and prefix in an array

2. Then traverse next prefix and get strlen(61870) =5, and compare this prefix to phone number, if matches, we will store that strlen and prefix in an array

3. and finally, find max(strlen) from array.

solution doesn't look very efficient, but you can improve it further!

Comment: BK435 it's because prefixes can vary in length and can overlap so it can't use the first matching prefix, it must use the most specific prefix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be a simple query with an order by based on the longest prefix and returning a limit of 1 record...  Something like...

```
select
      pp.*
   from
      phonePrefix pp
   where
      '61412345678' like pp.prefix + '%'
   order by
      length( trim( pp.prefix )) DESC
   limit 1
```

So, your phone number would match on

```
49 Australia at .0165 = "61" prefix length of prefix 2
62 Australia - Mobile at .075 = "614" prefix length of 3 <-- would be in first position and then limit 1 returns it instead of ID 49.
```

Now, if a phone number like '6188319383'
would return the values for #49 via "61" and #53 via "61883".

Simple query, might have to tweak it some, but principle is accurate and not positive of the actual data types you have numeric vs character.

Similar would happen if say you actually did have prefixes for

```
6
61
618
6188
61883
```

The 61883 would have a prefix length of 5, in descending order and the limit of 1 record would return it over the more generic shorter prefixes.